# Validating minutes and seconds where minutes digits can range from 1-2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, time

I have a time based regular expression that successfully validates minutes and seconds:

```
validates_format_of :duration, with: /\A(?!00:00)[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\Z/
```

The problem I have is that if the string `2:30` is entered I get a validation error. Instead it expects something like `02:30`. My first guess was to insert a two digit optional like `d{1,2}` but didn't know how to incorporate something like this with the negative lookahead I have in there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to the following, which makes the first digit optional:

```
/\A(?!00:00)[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\Z/
```

Adding the `?` after the initial `[0-5]` matcher will allow it to have 1 or 0 matches. This way, you won't be required to have the leading zero.

You can go one step further and change the range from `[0-5]` to `[1-5]` if you don't want a leading zero to be valid (therefore requiring 2:30 and not allowing 02:30):

```
/\A(?!00:00)[1-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\Z/
```

Comment: It would be nice if you also make the first zero optional in the lookahead.

Comment: @ndn What would that look like in comparison to what Wes has and which would be more performant?

Comment: @CarlEdwards, `(?!0?0:00)`. As to which would be more performant - Wes' version, but only marginally. My point was - if the first digit can be optional, you probably want to exclude `0:00` too.

Comment: True. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ndn I must note though with your negative lookahead I'm still able to bypass validation. Unless I have it written wrong: `/\A(?!0?0:00)[1-5]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\Z/`

Comment: @CarlEdwards, which case breaks it?

Comment: In reference to validating: **0:00**.

Comment: Hm, it should be working fine, at least [according to](http://rubular.com/r/KhtQUCPskH).

Comment: That's really strange. It must be my Rails syntax. I wonder why it's passing in my app despite the Rubular test?

Comment: False alarm. I think it was a caching issue on my side. Thanks so much for your help.